# error in mogodb status server after the installation put the comando # systemctl status mongod

Tags: mongodb, debian, graylog

I am installing mongodb in a debian machine but when i end the process and after that put the next command systemctl status mongod, the result is:

[image: 1]

So What can I do to revolv the error?

Thanks a lot.

I am trying to installa graylog system but I am sttoped with this error in mongo db...

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Have a look at mongod logfile, typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. Most likely `dbPath` folder does not exist or lags write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The failure was signal ILL:

> Illegal instruction. The ILL signal is sent to a process when it attempts to execute a malformed, unknown, or privileged instruction.

Starting with version 5.0 MongoDB requires that the CPU support the [Advanced Vector Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions).

The machine you are attempting to start mongod on does not support AVX.  You will need to either use a different computer, or downgrade to mongodb version 4.4 or earlier.

Comment: hi mister I am using  a virtual machine son maybe it is with wrong configuration so can you help me again please?

Comment: If the host machine CPU doesn't support AVX, I don't think the guest VM will either.  On Windows if hyper-v is running or any of the virtualization based security features are enabled, many virtualization apps won't be able to offer AVX (this includes VirtualBox).  I have been able to run mongod in a Ubuntu 18 VM on windows 10 using the windows subsystem for linux.

Comment: Ok, that was the error.